Compiler opton for detecting missing JNI prototypes?
While going through the exercise of renaming my namespace, I occasionally get tripped up by a situation where the function definitions incorporate the OLD packagename in the fct name.  For example:
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_mycompany_myoldpackagename_myfct(...)
{ ... }

but there is an updated prototype with the new package-name:
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_mycompany_mynewpackagename_myfct(...);

What's the compiler option to trap this, which is obviously a linker error?
As things are, my app builds, and loads...and crashes.  I want to avoid the last outcome.
Thanks! Charles.

The C++ compiler itself has no clue about this. Android studio has a custom linting rule though.

You can make an ad-hoc check for this by creating a dummy function that tries to take the address of all such functions:
void check_all_jni_functions() {
  void* functions[] = {
    &Java_com_mycompany_mynewpackagename_myfct,
    // others
  };
}

You can generate this list from your generated header file using something like:
grep -h -oE 'Java_\w+' generated.h | sed 's/.*/\&&,/'

